# How to detect server disconnection in Thrift?

Tags: c#, c++, rpc, thrift

Note: [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641170/thrift-server-detect-client-disconnections-c-library) asks a different thing (detecting *client* disconnection on the server side).

---

I have a C# Thrift client connected over a named pipe transport to a C++ Thrift service. I would like to detect *from the client* when the C++ service dies, i.e. when the connection is no longer usable. I tried looking at the TTransport.IsOpen property, but it stays `true` no matter what. Is there a clean way to implement this (without extending my service with a heartbeat feature)?

Comment: The `isOpen` only tells you whether the transport is considered being open. It does not validate any handles, sockets, pipes, ... Can't look at the sources right now, but is there a way to get a hold of the pipe handle maybe? Then perform some check (WinAPI?) against it, at least that's what I have in  mind.

Comment: It seems that the the IsOpen property is only updated when I attempt to use it. I'd rather not create a dependency on this particular transport implementation, but maybe I'll have to :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid dependency on the platform and even the chosen transport layer, I ended up adding a no-op `ping` call to my service. This is called periodically by the client from a background thread and does nothing on the server. The effect is that the `IsOpen` property of the pipe is updated and I also get an `IOException` when trying to call something. This is far from ideal but at least works and I was already wrapping my service for other reasons so I can hide this ugliness behind a nicer interface.